# How to submit a form in javascript and prevent default

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

How to submit a form in javascript and prevent default

Till now my html form (id="contact_form") had a `<input id="contact_send_msg" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">` and when it was clicked i would catch it correctly in js with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#contact_form").submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: this.method, 
            url: this.action, 
            data: new FormData(this), 
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            success: function (data) 
            {
                if(data.localeCompare("got your message") === 0)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    window.location = "index.php";
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Something went wrong, try again later');
                    alert(data);

                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

But then ,in order to add recaptcha, i replaced the

`<input id="contact_send_msg" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">`

with

`<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my key" data-callback="onSubmit">Submit</button>`

so i thought that with the following code i could achieve the same result but it doesn't go inside `$("#contact_form").submit(function(e){`

```
function onSubmit()
{
    alert("it is inside1");
    $("#contact_form").submit(function(e)
    {
        alert("it is inside2");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: this.method,
            url: this.action,
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                if(data.localeCompare("got your message") === 0)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    window.location = "index.php";
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Something went wrong, try again later');
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `data-callback="onSubmit"` does not automatically bind the click event on that control to `onSubmit` - you need to attach an event listener to the click event on `$(".g-recaptcha")`

Comment: whoever downvoted, can you explain?

Comment: Jaromanda i don't really get what you mean could explain it a bit more? The function is called when i click it, so i thought the only thing left is to submit the form in javascript and prevent default.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing the following but i'm sure there is a better way

```
function onSubmit()
{
    $("#contact_form").submit();
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#contact_form").submit(function(e)
    {
      //alert("enterededde");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: this.method,
            url: this.action, 
            data: new FormData(this), .
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            success: function (data)
            {
                if(data.localeCompare("Got your message") === 0)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    window.location = "index.php";
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Something went wrong, try again later');
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```